# Windows FSRM File Expiration Cleanup Script

Tags: powershell

I am testing FSRM in our environment and am running into an issue with cleaning up expired data based on amount of days/months of being in the expired folder.

I followed instructions from another site that stated that this script should work.

```
$Date = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-6) | get-date -UFormat "%Y-%m" $ExpiredDirectory = Get-ChildItem "C:\Expired Files\FQDN of Server" | where name -like "Expire Stale Data_$Date*" $ExpiredDirectory | Remove-Item -Recurse -whatif
```

The script does not work even without the -whatif test.

I modified the script and changed `AddMonths` to `AddDays`. as well as the `-UFormat "%Y-%m"` to `"%Y-%m-%d"`.

I might add that even before making the changes the script failed on "where name" so I changed to "Where-Object". My script new script looks as follows and now deletes more than I want to get deleted...

```
$Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-6) | get-date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d" 
$ExpiredDirectory = Get-ChildItem "D:\FSRMExpire\XServer" | 
    Where-Object -like "Expire Stale Data_$Date*" $ExpiredDirectory | Remove-Item -Recurse
```

I would have posted the link to where I got the script initially but if needed I can provide it.

Comment: Try following : $ExpiredDirectory = Get-ChildItem "C:\Expired Files\FQDN of Server" -Filter "Expire Stale Data_$Date.*" | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -le $tableDate}

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I forgot to mention that each time an FSRM job runs, it creates a directory similar to "2023-04-22_12-00-02".

Comment: My understanding of the initial script is that it would just evaluate whether or not to delete a directory based on the name of the directory instead of evaluating last modified or creation date... Please help me understand if I am thinking wrong.

Comment: I modified as follows and it did not delete anything: $Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) | get-date -UFormat "%Y-%m-%d" 
$ExpiredDirectory = Get-ChildItem "D:\FSRMExpire\ServerName" -Filter "Expire Stale Data_$Date.*" | 
Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -le $tableDate} | Remove-Item -Recurse